# Pass websocket connection to thread

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, json-rpc

I'm trying to add some functionality to a project which accepts TCP socket connections, to also accept WebSocket connections, but I'm not sure how to best integrate asyncio and threading.

How can I run a WebSocket server and pass the websocket connection on as a socket to be handled by a service in another thread.

```
from threading import Thread
from bsonrpc import JSONRpc
import websockets
from .myservices import services

def accept(socket):
    JSONRpc(socket, services)

def listen(s_socket):
    while True:
        socket, _ = s_socket.accept()
        accept(socket)

def main():

    # TCP Socket

    tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcp_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 1234))
    tcp_socket.listen(10)
    tcp_thread = Thread(target=listen, args=(tcp_socket,), daemon=False)
    tcp_thread.start()

    # Want to have the same as above but for WebSockets

    websocket = ??

    websocket_thread = Thread(target=listen, args=(websocket,), daemon=False)
    websocket_thread.start()
```

All the examples I can see for WebSockets pass a handler to the websockets.serve function, but I'm not sure how I would then have a socket I can pass on to the JSONRpc service.

Can anyone help me, or show me if I should be doing this another way?